# In the CP, How to make images bigger when the users select images?

Tags: plugin-development, control-panel, cp-dashboard

In the Control Panel, when users are selecting an image for the asset field, the thumbnails are too small in the popping up image modal. Is there any way to make the images bigger?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you're running Craft 3, you can click an asset and then hit SHIFT + SPACE to open a Lightbox with the image.

[image: Craft 3 Asset Lightbox/Modal]

Answer (score 2):

You can change the view at the top right corner
There is also a setting in your asset fields what the default view should be 
[image]

Comment: Thanks, it helped. But I'm still wondering if there is any api to do this without switching the view mode?

Comment: What do you want an API for? You can execute the Javascript to change the view and you can set the default setting. Do you want to change the view from another user dynamically?

Comment: Yeh, I've tried JS to make it done and it's working. I just prefer a craft way to achieve this :)

Comment: As I already said there are Craft ways to achieve it. You just need to ask properly